# 1с платформа: реализовать зависимость двух документов

Tags: 1с

Есть два документа. Они создаются независимо друг от друга разными пользователями. Первый документ "Распределение" содержит реквизиты "автомобиль", "водитель"; второй документ "Заявка" содержит такие же реквизиты.

Нужно при создании документа "Заявка", пользователь заполняет поле авто, если на это авто в этот день создан документ "Распределение", то автоматом заполняется поле "водитель", если нет, происходит сброс данных.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать это?

Comment: Я не дока в 1С, но может стоить смотреть дополнительно в сторону других объектов конфигурации? Таких как, к примеру, Регистр Сведений или Регистр Накоплений?

Comment: Хм, т.е. информацию взять из регистра, а не из документа... это идея, я попробую. Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд решение выглядит следующим образом:

1. Необходимо создать регистр сведений (подчиненный регистратору, периодичность: День)
2. Реализовать проведение документа Распределение, чтобы добавлялась запись в этот регистр
3. Реализовать в модуле менеджера регистра сведений метод, принимающий в качестве параметра автомобиль и дату и возвращающий водителя
4. Далее вариантов 2:

   4.1 В документе заявка при изменении поля вызывать метод из п. 3 и если тот вернул Неопределено, очищать значение и отображать сообщение пользователю с привязкой к полю

   4.2 В дополнение к п. 4.1 при выборе, отображать пользователю только те автомобили, для которых введено распределение. (можно создать отдельную форму выбора, например)

Comment: спасибо) буду пробовать. Потом отпишусь получилось или нет